# Looping through files using pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder with several files from one of the test from which I would like to take some values.
The files are named
"01 test1.txt", "02 test1.txt" ... "12 test1.txt".
Each file consists of four columns named "time", "hdisp", "vdisp" and "force".
What I would like to do in Python is to loop through those files and take the maximum value of column "vdisp" in pandas.
This should give me 12 values which I would place in an array for further calculation.
I have tried a for loop, but I cannot add iterator value to a string.

Comment: Are the text files actually in csv format? If that is the case, you could read each file into a dataframe, then apply the aggregate on that. If you could also show what you have already attempted and some example data, that would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot add iterator value to a string."? Do you mean you don't know how to turn a number to the coresponding filepath? If so you can do it by `f'{num:02d} test1.txt'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop with `range()` to construct the filename:

```
for x in range(1, 13):
    filename = "%02d test1.txt" % x
    # now you have the filename and can process it however you like
```